# Using certain R functions converts foreign language (korean) text to hexadecimal. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Tags: r

To start I've already saved encoding preferences to UTF-8

x = "안녕"

View(x)

```
    <U+C548><U+B155>
```

There are other functions in R that seem to cause the hexadecimal conversion as well. What is the reasoning behind this conversion and is there a way to prevent R from doing it?